# A master web site able to display products in other website which is independent

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a master website. And I have a set of customer website who have there own admin and store. They can apply in master website so that products in master website or store can be displayed in these customer store who have there own website.

Is it possible using magento, if so can any one help me to solve it.

eg.

**site 1.com is a master.**
     This site will have an admin and front end to display its own product.

other sites eg 2.com, 3.com 4.com will have there own admin and front end to display there own products.

site 2, 3, 4, etc can apply in site 1 such as products from site 1 can be displayed in site 2, 3, 4 ,etc.

Comment: Am a beginner in magento, is it possible to build a  separate module for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento has a great Multi-Store framework.

[Check this guide on Multi-Stores](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/)

Essentially, you can have multiple websites with multiple stores all served from the same Magento backed. You can centrally manage your products and orders, but serve them in multiple stores.

The framework is quite flexible, and so will provide you with everything you need to set it up in the way you require!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the clarification.
I think what you're looking for here is a solution that allows you to produce a 'feed' of your products. I don't think (to my knowledge) this is something Magento can support, though I'm sure there's plenty of scope for a custom module development on this matter.

Comment: Its not like one back end and multiple frontend. All other sites are not belongs to me. With the permission of others i need to display my products to others website.

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank for you update.

Comment: Is it possible to use any api to build it.

Comment: Provided the child stores all know how to read it, and you know how to integrate it, then I don't see why not.

Comment: One more doubt. Am a beginner in magento. I need to build a theme. I just have a psd in my hand. Is it advisable to build a theme by editing the existing rwd theme and make it into my theme.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question for this. It's not related to multi-store APIs.